# Erro Invalid argument em foreach

Tags: php

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['sendRecover'])) {
    $recover = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
    $readRec = read($link, 'up_users', "WHERE email = '$recover'");

    if (!$readRec) {
        $rc = mysqli_fetch_array($readRec) >= 1;
        echo '<span class="ms no">Erro: Email Inválido!</span>';
    } else {
        foreach ($readRec as $rec) {
            if ($rec['nivel'] == 1 || $rec['nivel'] == 2) {
              }
?>
```

Não sei o porque desse erro:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\wamp64\www\CURSOS\projeto_pro_php\admin\relembra_senha.php on line 15

Existe uma query mysqli antes  que vem de uma função mas o select esta certo, ja testei, a minha sintaxe ai que está errado e eu não acertei.

Comment: Esse warning regra geral significa que o `foreach` não está a receber um `array` como seria suposto. Sugiro que antes do `foreach` faça `var_dump($readRec);` para ter a certeza do que está exatamente a ser passado.

Comment: a varival não é um array retornou  um caminho, ai troquei por print_f, ai me retornou a quantidade de um registro, mas valeu!!

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
Primeiramente, tenha em mente que um aviso não é um erro.
O que pode ter gerado esse aviso é o fato do `foreach` ter em sua sintaxe o formato:

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
```

Assegure-se que a função `read()` retorne um array para `$readRec`.

Leia mais [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php), no manual do PHP.

Comment: Apesar de não compreender bem o código, discordo da sua afirmação de que avisos podem ser ignorados. Se gerou um aviso, é porque tem algo que pode resultar num problema, pode não ser agora, mas futuramente. Acho que sempre devemos ficar atentos até a alertas e procurar solucionar na medida do possivel.

Comment: Editei a resposta tendo em mente sua observação e outros detalhes que observei no código

Comment: a varival não é um array retornou  um caminho, ai troquei por print_f, ai me retornou a quantidade de um registro, mas valeu!!

Answer (score 0):

É sempre válido verificar a variável que vai para o foreach, precisamos sempre manter a integridade dos dados, garantindo que mesmo que não receba nada, esteja sempre de acordo com a estrutura da função, no seu caso, simplesmente verifique se é um array válido:

```
if ( !is_array($readRec) || count($readRec) < 1 ) {
    // Não é um array válido ou não possui conteúdo.
}
```

Comment: a varival não é um array retornou  um caminho, ai troquei por print_f, ai me retornou a quantidade de um registro, mas valeu!!